# Why should I use url-routing ? What are the benefits ? Is it a must for all SPAs?

Tags: url-routing

Why should I use url-routing (for example [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) , or [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing))?

What are the benefits ?

Is it a must for all SPAs ?

Can I add routing later ?

**I am complete newbee** to web development , can someone explain me what's the big deal about routing ?

If desktop apps can be without routing then why is so important for webapps?

Answer (score 1):

A server will hand off a client request to an application. That application is given the URL of the request but what should it do with it? That is the purpose of the router, to route the request to the appropriate handler of such requests inside the application.

Answer (score 0):

Why to use routing ?

- back button
- sharing links
- using bookmarks

answer from IRC (thanks to fkm !):

```
<joco42> but in theory, i could do an SPA without any routing right ?
no change in the url at all, ever
would that be possible?
<fkm> joco42: In theory. But the users wouldn't be able to use the back-button or share/bookmarks links.
```